# How to get the first row of dataframe grouped by multiple columns with aggregate function as count?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe where I want only the first row of each group(grouped using multiple columns) with aggregate function as count. This is what I have tried :

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 2.6, 2.5, 3.4,2.6,2.6,3.4,3.4,2.6,1.1,1.1,3.3], list('AAABBBBABCBDDD'), [1.1, 1.7, 2.5, 2.6, 3.3, 3.8,4.0,4.2,4.3,4.5,4.6,4.7,4.7,4.8], ['x/y/z','x/y','x/y/z/n','x/u','x','x/u/v','x/y/z','x','x/u/v/b','-','x/y','x/y/z','x','x/u/v/w'],['1','3','3','2','4','2','5','3','6','3','5','1','1','1']]).T
>>> df.columns = ['col1','col2','col3','col4','col5']
>>> df[['col1', 'col2', 'col4']].groupby(['col2', 'col4']).agg('count')
              col1
col2 col4
A    x           1
     x/y         1
     x/y/z       1
     x/y/z/n     1
B    x           1
     x/u         1
     x/u/v       1
     x/u/v/b     1
     x/y         1
     x/y/z       1
C    -           1
D    x           1
     x/u/v/w     1
     x/y/z       1
```

Expected output :

```
 col2 col4         col1
    A    x           1
    B    x           1
    C    -           1
    D    x           1
```

How can I get this first row ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html) by first level of index:

```
df2 = df1.groupby(level='col2').head(1)
#used first level
#df2 = df1.groupby(level=0).head(1)
print (df2)
           col1
col2 col4      
A    x        1
B    x        1
C    -        1
D    x        1
```

Or use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) by extract first level values with [`Index.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.duplicated.html) and inverted mask by `~`:

```
df2 = df1[~df1.index.get_level_values('col2').duplicated()]

#used first level
#df2 = df1[~df1.index.get_level_values(0).duplicated()]
print (df2)
           col1
col2 col4      
A    x        1
B    x        1
C    -        1
D    x        1
```

Comment: Hi can you tell me how can I display in descending order and then take the first one. That will be very helpful. Thanks

Comment: do you think sorting by  `df1 = df[['col1', 'col2', 'col4']].groupby(['col2', 'col4']).agg('count').sort_index(0, ascending=False)` before my solution?

Comment: what sorry I didn't get it

Comment: I want to sort the count inside for each group. How do I do that @jezrael

Comment: it's not obvious which data you're using for this example (is it from the second line of the original post?)

Comment: @baxx - hmmm, now not sure if understand, is possible create new question if not working solution from comment?